# Quais são as regras para construir um e-mail em HTML?

Tags: html, css, email

Estou para construir um e-mail em HTML, mas vejo que há diferenças para uma página comum de website. Quero que o e-mail em HTML possua css e que apareça tanto no acesso por desktop quanto no tablet e celular, além disso deve mostrar algumas imagens no corpo da mensagem.

O que é permitido e como se faz para apresentar HTML estilizado no e-mail enviado?

Existe um padrão ou boas práticas?

Comment: Prepare-se para uma jornada dolorosa...

Comment: Basicamente se atenha ao HTML 4.x. O resto, são pequenos detalhes. Evite CSS.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Se nós desenvolvedores achamos complicado ter compatibilidade entre navegadores imagina clientes de email, bom, cada um implementa o que quiser na hora que quiser, então em resumo, você pode procurar um site que te mostre a compatibilidade de htm/css  e escolher a melhor abordagem para o seu html.

[CampaignMonitor - Email Client CSS Support](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/)

[MailChimp - Email Client CSS Support](http://templates.mailchimp.com/resources/email-client-css-support/)

Existem artigos dizendo sobre boas práticas, sobre não usar css no `<head>` ou não usar `background-image`, a maioria delas estão defasadas.

Outra abordagem legal é utilizar templates, neste site: [Zurb - Template emails](http://foundation.zurb.com/emails/email-templates.html) Você pode encontrar um template clicar em View Tests e ele fará uma simulação em diferentes servidores de email, depois de encontrar um template com as características que você necessita é so baixar ou dar um crtl+u para ver como ele montou.

Ah, é claro eles utilizam https://litmus.com/ que permite criar preview dos seus templates antes de envia-los.